# how to use conditional input in bootstrap 4 form using ajax in php?

Tags: php, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I m using conditional form in php which is working fine but when i call a model containing form using ajax ...  the condition fields are not working. don't know what is wrong...  can anybody help me out here

this is my calling function

```
<script>
function addProd(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("addproductblock").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("addproductblock").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/test.php?pid="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

button to call the function

```
<a onClick="addProd(<?php echo $row_product['productid']; ?>)" href="#addproduct" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm make-favorite"> <i class="fa fa-certificate"></i><span>Add To Store</span> </a>
```

model

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addproduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="addproductblock"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Get file for ajax test.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/conditionize.flexible.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.conditional').conditionize();
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">.msg {color:red;}</style>
<div class="modal-header">
   <h4 class="modal-title"><i class=" icon-mail-2"></i>Adding </h4>
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span
      class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
   <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
         <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="homedel" id="homedel"> Home delivery</label></p>
         <p class="conditional" data-condition="#homedel">
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="homedeltyp" value="paid" id="homedeltyp_0">
            Paid home delivery</label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="homedeltyp" value="free" id="homedeltyp_1">
            Free home delivery</label>
            <br>
         </p>
         <p class="conditional" data-condition="#homedel && homedeltyp">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cod" id="cod"> Cash on delivery</label>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send message!</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try with jquery ajax

Comment: tried same result

Comment: wait ... thanks it is working now